# Oracle - Order of next row determined by previous row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

1. Coordinate_ID (primary key)
2. X_Coordinate
3. Y_Coordinate
4. Group_ID
5. Weight

All values are numeric, none are null.

The query gets all columns, but needs to order them in a particular way.

First, order by the sum of the Weight descending, partitioned by GroupID. If tied, order by GroupID.

For each Group_ID, compute the centroid of the X_Coordinate and Y_Coordinate for its rows. Weight doesn't factor in here, just the coordinates.

The first row for a given Group_ID should be the row with coordinates furthest from the centroid.

Each subsequent row for a Group_ID should be the one with coordinates closest to the previous row.

In case of distance ties, the row with the lower Coordinate_ID should go first.

I've tried looking into:

1. Windowing functions (LAG). Problem here is that LAG requires an ORDER clause, but the LAG is being used to determine the ordering.
2. MODEL. Didn't know about this until I started searching for a solution to this problem. Looks like a powerful tool, but understanding how/if it applies here isn't clear right now.
3. Hierarchical queries. Very little experience with this. It looks like I have the root for each partition (the point furthest from the centroid), but I don't see how to get the distance calculation worked in.

EDIT:
Sample data.

```
Coordinate_ID | X_Coordinate | Y_Coordinate | Group_ID | Weight
            1 |            2 |            4 |        1 |      5
            2 |            1 |            1 |        1 |     10
            3 |            9 |           10 |        1 |     10
            4 |            5 |            5 |        1 |      2
            5 |            7 |            2 |        2 |     10
            6 |            8 |            4 |        2 |      2
```

First, sum the weight for each group.

Group 1 = 5 + 10 + 10 + 2 = 27

Group 2 = 10 + 2 = 12

So Group 1 goes before Group 2 because it has a higher SUM(Weight).

Looking at Group 1:

Get the centroid.

X = (2 + 1 + 9 + 5)/4 = 4.25

Y = (4 + 1 + 10 + 5)/4 = 5

Centroid is (4.25, 5)

Distance from centroid:

```
Coordinate_ID 1 -> SQRT((4.25-2)^2 + (5-4)^2) ~= 2.46
Coordinate_ID 2 -> SQRT((4.25-1)^2 + (5-1)^2) = 5.15
Coordinate_ID 3 -> SQRT((4.25-9)^2 + (5-10)^2) ~= 6.90
Coordinate_ID 4 -> SQRT((4.25-5)^2 + (5-5)^2) ~= 0.75
```

So the first row is ID 3, since it's the furthest from the centroid.

Comparing the distance to ID 3.

```
Coordinate_ID 1 -> SQRT((9-2)^2 + (10-4)^2) ~= 9.22
Coordinate_ID 2 -> SQRT((9-1)^2 + (10-1)^2) ~= 12.04
Coordinate_ID 4 -> SQRT((9-5)^2 + (10-5)^2) ~= 6.40
```

ID 4 is next, since it's closest.

Now comparing distance to ID 4.

```
Coordinate_ID 1 -> SQRT((5-2)^2 + (5-4)^2) ~= 3.16
Coordinate_ID 2 -> SQRT((5-1)^2 + (5-1)^2) ~= 5.66
```

ID 1 is closest, so it's next.

That leaves ID 2 as the last one.

Order is thus: 3, 4, 1, 2 for Group 1.

A similar procedure would be followed for Group 2.

Centroid X: (7 + 8) / 2 = 7.5

Centroid Y: (2 + 4) / 2 = 3

Centroid: (7.5, 3)

Comparing with the rows:

```
Coordinate_ID 5 -> SQRT((7.5-7)^2 + (3-2)^2) ~= 1.12
Coordinate_ID 6 -> SQRT((7.5-8)^2 + (3-4)^2) ~= 1.12
```

As it's tied, the first row is that with a lower Coordinate_ID, which is 5.

Only one row is left, Coordinate_ID 6.

So Group 2 order: 5, 6

End result:

```
Coordinate_ID | X_Coordinate | Y_Coordinate | Group_ID | Weight
            3 |            9 |           10 |        1 |     10
            4 |            5 |            5 |        1 |      2
            1 |            2 |            4 |        1 |      5
            2 |            1 |            1 |        1 |     10
            5 |            7 |            2 |        2 |     10
            6 |            8 |            4 |        2 |      2
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  From what you describe, I think you need a recursive CTE or similar construct.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to make your question easier to understand.